# Django - sorting foreign key objects by date

Tags: python, django, filter, foreign-keys

I have the following django models:

```
class Application(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField(max_length=50)      

class Release(models.Model):
   application = models.ForeignKey(Application)
   release_date = models.DateField("Release Date")
```

I.e An `Application` can have many `Releases`. A `Release` may be historical, or it may be a planned future release (upcoming)

In my django view, I currently return a table of application names.
I would like to return a table of application names and the next upcoming release date. If there is no upcoming release, it should just be blank.

My view currently looks like this:

```
def index(request): 
  all_apps = Application.objects.all()
  template = loader.get_template('index.html')
  context = RequestContext(request, {'all_apps': all_apps})
  return HttpResponse(template.render(context))
```

How can I also supply the 'next upcoming release' for each app, so it can be rendered in the template?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provide a method on the Application

```
class Application(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    def next_upcoming_release(self):
        future_releases = self.release_set.filter(release_date__gte=datetime.datetime.now())
        return future_releases.order_by('release_date').first()
```

You can call this in the template with `{{ application.next_upcoming_release }}`.

Comment: So django automatically provides the `release_set` variable?
So any foreign key collection can be accessed by `objectname_set`?

Comment: Yes (unless you explicitly set a `related_name` when defining the ForeignKey field, in which case you use that instead.) See [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/queries/#backwards-related-objects).